# How does an explicitly scoped this keyword in java work?

Tags: java

I know `this` key word is used to point to current class fields and to call constructor like:

```
class A{
String name;
  public A(String name)
  {
   this.name=name;
   this.(name.length());
  }

  public(int len)
  {
   //some code here
  }
}
```

but my I recently came across:

```
class B extends A
{
A varA = B.this;
}
```

I don't understand how B.this works. can any one elaborate in detail

Comment: [self reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) / [jls about this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3)

Comment: `A varA = this;` would be enough here.

Comment: `A varA = B.this;` is equivalent of `A varA = this;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`B.this` is a reference to `B` class instance.

as `B` extends `A` it is possible to declare a variable of type `A` and assign it to a reference to `B` class instance.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you have, `B.this` is equivalent to `this`, so it's not very illustrative.  Scoped `this` declarations are far more valuable when you start working with inner classes....

```
class Outer {
  public void doSomething() {
  }

  class Inner {
    public void doSomething() {
      Outer.this.doSomething();
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the use of `Outer.this` in the `Inner` class.  Without it, the inner class would have no way of disambiguating between the `this` that referred to the Inner instance and the `this` that referred to the Outer instance.

Answer (score 0):

The `B.this` means that you are getting the reference/pointer of the B class instance, **B** inherits from **A** so what you are actually doing is Initializing your **A** with the reference/pointer of **B**.

The `B.this` is useful when you are calling the instance of `B class` inside a `anonymous/inner` classes.

You can also call `this` which is equivalent to `B.this` but you cant call `this` in a `anonymous/inner` classes or else you'll get the instance of them not the `class B` instance.

Comment: @BackSlash lawl only one result.. ahaha

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the `this` keyword is used to *refer* to the instance of a class.

When you do

```
this.name
```

you are referring to the attribute `name` from the actual instance of the class `A`.

When you do

```
B.this
```

you are referring to the `B` class intance.